# Meteor google oauth - error 400

Tags: meteor, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, meteor-accounts

I get an 400 error when I try to do any kind of authorization using  oauth. 
I tried different browsers and different code implementations, but still failed.
So I cloned a simple app from Levelup tutorial repo on [Github](https://github.com/leveluptuts/Meteor-1.4-React-For-Everyone/tree/master/FINAL%20CODE), and after inserting secret key from api's I'm still getting 400 error
API parameters:
 Authorized redirect URIs - 
http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close
Authorized JavaScript origins: http://localhost:3000
Here's first part when I'm installing example Meteor App from git:

[image]
here's second part when I'm inserting google Api credentials and got an error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few days of googling, checking and so on...
I watched an old video on youtube, and saw that a tutor used `Authorized redirect URIs` without ending ***?close***
Correct Authorized redirect URIs - http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google
And I used incorrect http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close